# How to set a WORM Strategy in OSS

Tags: alibaba-cloud

WORM (Write Once Read Many) strategy is used to specify the protection period of files in OSS Bucket in Alibaba Cloud.

How can I set WORM strategy in OSS.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set WORM Strategy at bucket level. To set the WORM Strategy, Please follow the below-stated procedure:

> 1) Log-on to the OSS console
>
> 2) Create or Select the bucket
>
> 3) Click the Basic Settings and locate the WORM Settings and Configure
>   as per your requirements - Set the Lifecycle of WORM Strategy and
>   click OK
>
> 4) WORM strategy will be created, it will be in IN_PROGRESS state.
>
> 5) Click Lock.

Note: After a WORM strategy is locked, it cannot be deleted, but you can extend the lifecyle